How to access https://localhost:44392/API/Get_Incomming_Message via AJAX in Chromium despite "Refused to connect" error?
The connection to 'https://localhost:44392/API/Get_Incomming_Message' was refused due to a violation of the Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://*.whatsapp.net".
I'm using a C# Chromium browser WinForms application, and I've tried various approaches to resolve this error. This includes attempts to disable CSP and adding the meta tag with JavaScript, but the issue persists.

Could you please post the code with which you are trying to instantiate a content security policy. default-src example HTTPS example
